# Загрузка нескольких файлов на гугл диск

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

У меня есть скрипт который загружает файл на гугл диск и переименовывает его на текст который введен   в  `input type="text"`. Как реализовать функцию, чтобы если в `input type="file"` загружено более одного файла, то на  гугл диске в папке `folder` создалась дополнительная папка с названием значения `input type="text"` и в нее загрузились эти файлы ?

```
<form id="myForm" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)"> 
     <input id = "file_name" name="file_name" type="text" class="form-control">
     <input id="myFile" name="myFile" type="file" class="form-control-file" multiple>
</form>
<script>
function handleFormSubmit(formObject){
     google.script.run.withSuccessHandler().uploadFiles(formObject);
}
</script>


function uploadFiles(formObject) {
    var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('id');
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Name");
    var fileUrl = "";
    var fileName = "";
    var allFiles = formObject.myFile.files;
    var file = folder.createFile(blob);
    file.setName(formObject.file_name)
```